Error while running app using wine ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I just installed a new app (traktor pro 3 ) using Wine and PlayOnLinux
when I run the app I get the error below. Can you help, please
 0x000000007bc994a4 DbgBreakPoint in ntdll: int $3

 Modules:

 Module Address                 Debug info  Name (220 modules)

 - PE             240000-          24c000   Deferred        vcruntime140_1
 - PE             260000-          269000   Deferred        msvcp140_1
 - PE             270000-          29f000   Deferred        msvcp140_2
 - ELF          7a800000-        7aa0b000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
 -   \-PE           7a850000-        7aa0b000   \               opengl32
 - ELF          7b400000-        7b829000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
 -   \-PE           7b420000-        7b829000   \               kernel32
 - ELF          7bc00000-        7bd33000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
 -   \-PE           7bc20000-        7bd33000   \               ntdll
 - ELF          7c000000-        7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
 - PE          140000000-       15d140000   Deferred        traktor
 - PE          180000000-       1803b9000   Deferred        libbeatport
 - ELF      708259fc9000-    708259fee000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
 - ELF      708259fee000-    70825a0a8000   Deferred        libzstd.so.1
 - ELF      70825a0a8000-    70825a0da000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
 - ELF      70825a0da000-    70825a0fc000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
 - ELF      70825a0fc000-    70825a244000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
 - ELF      70825a244000-    70825a251000   Deferred        libcap.so.2
 - ELF      70825a251000-    70825a331000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
 - ELF      70825a331000-    70825a380000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
 - ELF      70825a380000-    70825a393000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
 - ELF      70825a393000-    70825a3a1000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
 - ELF      70825a3a1000-    70825a442000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
 - ELF      70825a442000-    70825a496000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
 - ELF      70825a496000-    70825a49d000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
 - ELF      70825a49d000-    70825a4aa000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
 - ELF      70825a4aa000-    70825a4b0000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
 - ELF      70825a4b0000-    70825a4dc000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
 - ELF      70825a4dc000-    70825a5a5000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
 - ELF      70825a5a5000-    70825a5c1000   Deferred        kerberos<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825a5b0000-    70825a5c1000   \               kerberos
 - ELF      70825a5c1000-    70825a5c9000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
 - ELF      70825a5c9000-    70825a5d5000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
 - ELF      70825a5d5000-    70825a5e8000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
 - ELF      70825a5e8000-    70825a5ed000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
 - ELF      70825a5ed000-    70825a5fa000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
 - ELF      70825a5fa000-    70825a606000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
 - ELF      70825a606000-    70825a60d000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
 - ELF      70825a60d000-    70825a61c000   Deferred        libmd.so.0
 - ELF      70825a61c000-    70825a632000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
 - ELF      70825a632000-    70825a63a000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
 - ELF      70825a63a000-    70825a663000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
 - ELF      70825a663000-    70825a7a0000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
 - ELF      70825a7a0000-    70825a7b4000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
 - ELF      70825a7cc000-    70825a87e000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825a7e0000-    70825a87e000   \               winex11
 - ELF      70825a87e000-    70825a88a000   Deferred        libffi.so.8
 - ELF      70825a88a000-    70825a90e000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
 - ELF      70825a90e000-    70825a956000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.6
 - ELF      70825a956000-    70825a9ab000   Deferred        libnettle.so.8
 - ELF      70825a9ab000-    70825a9c1000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
 - ELF      70825a9c1000-    70825ab6e000   Deferred        libunistring.so.5
 - ELF      70825ab6e000-    70825ab90000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
 - ELF      70825ab90000-    70825ad34000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
 - ELF      70825ad34000-    70825af2e000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
 - ELF      70825af32000-    70825af46000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825af40000-    70825af46000   \               api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
 - ELF      70825b05f000-    70825b08a000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
 - ELF      70825b08a000-    70825b0db000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
 - ELF      70825b0db000-    70825b0fe000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
 - ELF      70825b0fe000-    70825b136000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
 - ELF      70825b136000-    70825b14a000   Deferred        libbz2.so.1.0
 - ELF      70825b14a000-    70825b216000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
 - ELF      70825b218000-    70825b21d000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
 - ELF      70825b22e000-    70825b25a000   Deferred        propsys<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b240000-    70825b25a000   \               propsys
 - ELF      70825b25a000-    70825b272000   Deferred        mfreadwrite<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b260000-    70825b272000   \               mfreadwrite
 - ELF      70825b272000-    70825b2a3000   Deferred        mfplat<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b280000-    70825b2a3000   \               mfplat
 - ELF      70825b2a3000-    70825b2c3000   Deferred        concrt140<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b2b0000-    70825b2c3000   \               concrt140
 - ELF      70825b2c3000-    70825b3e8000   Deferred        msvcr120<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b2f0000-    70825b3e8000   \               msvcr120
 - ELF      70825b3e8000-    70825b3fc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b3f0000-    70825b3fc000   \               api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825b3fc000-    70825b423000   Deferred        combase<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b400000-    70825b423000   \               combase
 - ELF      70825b423000-    70825b438000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b430000-    70825b438000   \               api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825b438000-    70825b44e000   Deferred        authz<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b440000-    70825b44e000   \               authz
 - ELF      70825b44e000-    70825b468000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b450000-    70825b468000   \               userenv
 - ELF      70825b468000-    70825b499000   Deferred        kernelbase<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b470000-    70825b499000   \               kernelbase
 - ELF      70825b499000-    70825b4ae000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b4a0000-    70825b4ae000   \               api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
 - ELF      70825b4ae000-    70825b4de000   Deferred        odbc32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b4c0000-    70825b4de000   \               odbc32
 - ELF      70825b4de000-    70825b4f3000   Deferred        winusb<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b4e0000-    70825b4f3000   \               winusb
 - ELF      70825b4f3000-    70825b50b000   Deferred        powrprof<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b500000-    70825b50b000   \               powrprof
 - ELF      70825b50b000-    70825b53d000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b510000-    70825b53d000   \               msacm32
 - ELF      70825b53d000-    70825b609000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b550000-    70825b609000   \               winmm
 - ELF      70825b609000-    70825b624000   Deferred        hid<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b610000-    70825b624000   \               hid
 - ELF      70825b624000-    70825b69e000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b630000-    70825b69e000   \               dbghelp
 - ELF      70825b69e000-    70825b6f4000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b6b0000-    70825b6f4000   \               d3d9
 - ELF      70825b6f4000-    70825b740000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b700000-    70825b740000   \               winspool
 - ELF      70825b740000-    70825b797000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b750000-    70825b797000   \               usp10
 - ELF      70825b797000-    70825b90e000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b7a0000-    70825b90e000   \               comctl32
 - ELF      70825b90e000-    70825ba12000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825b920000-    70825ba12000   \               comdlg32
 - ELF      70825ba12000-    70825ba2c000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ba20000-    70825ba2c000   \               wtsapi32
 - ELF      70825ba2c000-    70825ba57000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ba30000-    70825ba57000   \               imm32
 - ELF      70825ba57000-    70825bae2000   Deferred        dwrite<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ba60000-    70825bae2000   \               dwrite
 - ELF      70825bae2000-    70825bb25000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825baf0000-    70825bb25000   \               dxgi
 - ELF      70825bb25000-    70825bbbb000   Deferred        d3d11<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825bb30000-    70825bbbb000   \               d3d11
 - ELF      70825bbbb000-    70825bbf5000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825bbc0000-    70825bbf5000   \               netapi32
 - ELF      70825bbf5000-    70825bc38000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825bc00000-    70825bc38000   \               secur32
 - ELF      70825bc38000-    70825bc51000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825bc40000-    70825bc51000   \               shcore
 - ELF      70825bc51000-    70825be00000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825bc80000-    70825be00000   \               ole32
 - ELF      70825be00000-    70825c815000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825be20000-    70825c815000   \               shell32
 - ELF      70825c821000-    70825c9a3000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825c850000-    70825c9a3000   \               oleaut32
 - ELF      70825c9a3000-    70825c9c1000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825c9b0000-    70825c9c1000   \               jsproxy
 - ELF      70825c9c1000-    70825ca09000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825c9d0000-    70825ca09000   \               winhttp
 - ELF      70825ca09000-    70825ca9c000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ca20000-    70825ca9c000   \               shlwapi
 - ELF      70825ca9c000-    70825cac9000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825caa0000-    70825cac9000   \               mpr
 - ELF      70825cac9000-    70825cae5000   Deferred        libz.so.1
 - ELF      70825cae8000-    70825cafd000   Deferred        api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825caf0000-    70825cafd000   \               api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1
 - ELF      70825cafd000-    70825cb94000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cb10000-    70825cb94000   \               wininet
 - ELF      70825cb94000-    70825cbd3000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cba0000-    70825cbd3000   \               uxtheme
 - ELF      70825cbd3000-    70825cc79000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cbe0000-    70825cc79000   \               rpcrt4
 - ELF      70825cc79000-    70825ccfc000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cc90000-    70825ccfc000   \               setupapi
 - ELF      70825ccfc000-    70825cd15000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cd00000-    70825cd15000   \               dwmapi
 - ELF      70825cd15000-    70825cebc000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cd30000-    70825cebc000   \               wined3d
 - ELF      70825cebc000-    70825cf65000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ced0000-    70825cf65000   \               ddraw
 - ELF      70825cf65000-    70825cf78000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
 - ELF      70825cf7b000-    70825cf90000   Deferred        avrt<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cf80000-    70825cf90000   \               avrt
 - ELF      70825cf90000-    70825cfc4000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cfa0000-    70825cfc4000   \               iphlpapi
 - ELF      70825cfc4000-    70825d0f5000   Dwarf           ucrtbase<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825cff0000-    70825d0f5000   \               ucrtbase
 - ELF      70825d0f5000-    70825d24c000   Deferred        msvcp140<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d130000-    70825d24c000   \               msvcp140
 - ELF      70825d24c000-    70825d400000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d260000-    70825d400000   \               gdi32
 - ELF      70825d400000-    70825d697000   Deferred        user32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d420000-    70825d697000   \               user32
 - ELF      70825d698000-    70825d69e000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
 - ELF      70825d69e000-    70825d6e2000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d6b0000-    70825d6e2000   \               ws2_32
 - ELF      70825d6e2000-    70825d6ff000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d6f0000-    70825d6ff000   \               wsock32
 - ELF      70825d7ff000-    70825d900000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825d810000-    70825d900000   \               crypt32
 - ELF      70825df7b000-    70825df8f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825df80000-    70825df8f000   \               api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825df8f000-    70825dfa3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825df90000-    70825dfa3000   \               api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825dfa3000-    70825dfbb000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825dfb0000-    70825dfbb000   \               api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825dfbb000-    70825dfd0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825dfc0000-    70825dfd0000   \               api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825dfd0000-    70825dfea000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825dfe0000-    70825dfea000   \               api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825dfea000-    70825e000000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825dff0000-    70825e000000   \               api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e000000-    70825e212000   Deferred        libc.so.6
 - ELF      70825e214000-    70825e229000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e220000-    70825e229000   \               api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e229000-    70825e23e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e230000-    70825e23e000   \               api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e23e000-    70825e254000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e240000-    70825e254000   \               api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e254000-    70825e26b000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e260000-    70825e26b000   \               api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e26b000-    70825e300000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e280000-    70825e300000   \               advapi32
 - ELF      70825e400000-    70825e7a7000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
 - ELF      70825e7ab000-    70825e7b9000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
 - ELF      70825e7b9000-    70825e7ce000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e7c0000-    70825e7ce000   \               api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e7ce000-    70825e7e4000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e7d0000-    70825e7e4000   \               api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0
 - ELF      70825e7e4000-    70825e809000   Deferred        bcrypt<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e7f0000-    70825e809000   \               bcrypt
 - ELF      70825e809000-    70825e824000   Deferred        version<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825e810000-    70825e824000   \               version
 - ELF      70825e924000-    70825e951000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
 - ELF      70825e951000-    70825ea3a000   Deferred        libm.so.6
 - ELF      70825ea3c000-    70825ea41000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
 - ELF      70825ea41000-    70825ea46000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
 - ELF      70825ea47000-    70825ea5e000   Deferred        vcruntime140<elf>
 -   \-PE       70825ea50000-    70825ea5e000   \               vcruntime140
 - ELF      70825ea60000-    70825ea9a000   Deferred        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 - ELF      7ffe207e5000-    7ffe207e7000   Deferred        [vdso].so
 - Threads:
 - process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
 - 0000000e services.exe
 -  00000029    0
 -  00000020    0
 -  00000013    0
 -  00000010    0
 -  0000000f    0
 - 00000011 winedevice.exe
 -  00000018    0
 -  00000017    0
 -  00000016    0
 -  00000012    0
 - 0000001e plugplay.exe
 -  00000022    0
 -  00000021    0
 -  0000001f    0
 - 00000023 winedevice.exe
 -  00000030    0
 -  0000002b    0
 -  0000002a    0
 -  00000024    0
 - 00000031 (D) C:\Program Files\Native Instruments\Traktor Pro 3\Traktor.exe
 -  00000032    0 <==
 - 00000033 explorer.exe
 -  00000037    0
 -  00000036    0
 -  00000035    0
 -  00000034    0

System information:
Wine build: wine-3.20
Platform: x86_64
Version: Windows 10
Host system: Linux
Host version: 6.8.0-35-generic

